# Trying to get the text only from a specific table row using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl, domxpath

Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$url = 'https://www.fibank.bg/bg/valutni-kursove/page/461';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "ChosenSite=www; SportsDirect_AnonymousUserCurrency=GBP; language=en-GB");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);

$xpath = new \DOMXpath($doc);
$value = $xpath->query('//td[em="GBP"]/parent::tr/td[last()]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

print_r($value);
```

With this code I am trying to parse the URL and get the line from the table which contains `GBP` and the get the text from the last `td`.

However my code seems to be not working. Where is my mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOMDocument/Xpath - How to get specific row from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555712/domdocument-xpath-how-to-get-specific-row-from-table)

Comment: No it is not solving my problem.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: It is not displaying any results..

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this line?

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

In addition to saying, "I don't care about security, please hack me!" this is incorrect usage and should be set to a constant. Try using a modern security protocol instead:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

You will have much better luck.